# Uploading File IN GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I am getting this error while uploading file from postman.

```
(node:13648) [DEP0135] DeprecationWarning: ReadStream.prototype.open() is deprecated
```

My node version is 15.0. I'm using apollo-server-express. And this is my code

```
export const processUpload = async (file) => {
  const {
    createReadStream, mimetype, encoding, filename
  } = await file;
  const path = `uploads/${uuid()}${filename}`;
  const stream = createReadStream();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stream
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path))
      .on('finish', () => {
        resolve({
          success: true,
          message: 'Successfully Uploaded',
          mimetype,
          filename,
          encoding,
          location: path
        });
      })
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error Event Emitted', err);
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your node version is high, please add this in package.js file.

```
"resolutions": {
    "**/**/fs-capacitor": "^6.2.0",
    "**/graphql-upload": "^11.0.0"
}
```